# Rename bulk files

Tags: powershell

I want to rename files in bulk using PowerShell for example:

- `my-file-name-photo.jpg` to `my-file-name-new-photo.jpg`
- `this file name photo.jpg` to `this file name new photo.jpg`
- `this is best image.jpg` to `this is best new image.jpg`

"new" is for ex. word I want to add in file name.

Comment: The first example have a `-` between the words whereas the other a space. Decide what you want...

Comment: yes some files name with - some with space .. this is not problem i can manage my self . please provide help in space names file .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$names = 'my-file-name-photo.jpg',    #'my-file-name-new-photo.jpg'
         'this file name photo.jpg',  #'this file name new photo.jpg
         'this is best image.jpg'     #this is best new image.jpg

$names | ForEach { $_ -replace '(.)(photo|image)', '$1new$1$2' }
```

This will do the string replacements you describe. It looks for any character (space or dash) followed by 'photo' or 'image' and puts 'new' in front, with the same separator.

Use with `Rename-Item` (Martin Brandl's answer) to rename files, e.g. at the PowerShell prompt:

```
cd c:\users\yourname\Documents\Photos
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '(.)(photo|image)', '$1new$1$2' }
```

Comment: hi thanks for answer and your time . there are bulk files in folder almost 200 so in this i need to put all files name in $names = 'my-file-name-photo.jpg',    #'my-file-name-new-photo.jpg'
         'this file name photo.jpg',  #'this file name new photo.jpg
         'this is best image.jpg'     #this is best new image.jpg  or it will do all files rename

Comment: I've edited in something to get the files and rename them.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Get-ChildItem](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113308) cmdlet to retrieve the files and pipe them to the [Rename-Item](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113382) cmdlet. Example which using spaces (as requested in your comment):

```
Get-ChildItem 'c:\tmp' | 
    Rename-Item -NewName {('{0} new{1}' -f $_.BaseName, $_.Extension) }
```

Comment: thanks its work , but not as i need .. it add new in the end of file name like my name photo new.jpg not like my name new photo.jpg